# Where can I find the declaration of `$_wp_theme_features`?

Tags: php, functions, theme-development, customization, variables

Where can I find the declaration of the global array `$_wp_theme_features` on WordPress core?

Comment: It'll be declared global in all the places it's used. current_theme_supports and add_theme_support are the obvious places. What is it you actually want to do?

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook I mean, in what specific .php file?